# Algorithm for finding a regex for a list of "words"

Tags: regular-expression

I just discovered this website and was amazed. Somehow this challenge popped into my mind:
Provided a very long list of words; Write or describe an algorithm which finds a regex to match them all.

Ex.: A very long list of Dates, model-numbers, CD-Codes, ISBNs et cetera.

I hope it's not too big or does not belong here. Please refer to downvote in that case but write a comment and I will delete this.

Edit: Sorry at my clumsy attempt. I fear there is not a very sharp goal.
Of course .* is not what I look for :) Here are some specifications:

- It has to match all *words*
- It has to group characters and find out what kind of characters are in that group, e.g. identify that an american date always consits of one to four numbers, then a slash etc.
- It does not need to be able to identify transverses etc
- There is a huge list of not-to-match-examples available as well

Winner is the one who can write a code which does what I described for one of my examples (or a similar one). In case that no code is committed, the winner is the one who can convince me, that the described algorithm *could* work.

Comment: something like `.*` ?

Comment: What's the winning criterion? Shortest code? Shortest regex? Something else? Does the regex need to match *only* the words?

Comment: I'm afraid your spec still isn't very solid. I don't know what you mean by your third bullet point. How long is a "huge list" (which can btw easily satisfied for any finite definition of "huge", with the expression `^.{n}$`, where `n`  is the longest input string). And how should the grouping work? If my input is `foo`, `bar`, `abc` I can always form a pattern `[fba][oab][orc]`, but that doesn't make a lot of sense. Or `[abcfor]{3}`. It's very unclear what a valid solution has to do.

Comment: Your problem is "regex golf". Search this site for it, or google it.

Comment: What about removing not-to-match list and asking for the shortest regex on some hidden set of tests?

Comment: [You might be interested in this.](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/xkcd1313.ipynb?create=1)

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8:

```java
public class Reg{

    public static void main(String... args){
        System.out.println(args[0].replaceAll(",", "|"));
    }

}
```

Matches only the strings inputed. Expects input to be of form:

goodWord1,goodWord2,goodWord3...(space)badWord1,badWord2,badWord3...

**Edit:** Edited for new requirements. Now accepts a list of bad words also. It also now works in Java 7.

Comment: Good quick answer. But not what I looked for. Sorry. I gave some more details.

Comment: @3244611user It matches **only** the words in the input sequence. It matches no other words. You don't even need a list of not-to-match examples. See next program for one that finds the shortest answer.